# What dos the ranges means in the coverage json file?

Tags: json, google-chrome-devtools

After exporting the json file from the Coverage tool in DevChrome Tools I got this code (only a sample):

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://www.cfcarehospitalar.com.br/skin/frontend/codazon_fastest/default/css/styles.css",
    "ranges": [
      {
        "start": 153,
        "end": 237
      },
```

Does this ranges means the line of the styles.css file?

This file is minified and when I unminified all green selectors scrapped by the coverage tool doesn't belong to the ranges json file is recording.

So I really do not understand what it means. I'll appreciate some explanation. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The ranges represent the sections of used code.

`url` is the file that was analyzed, `text` is the full text of the file. `ranges` are the substrings of `text` that were used.

If you take all of the substrings and concatenate them together, you'll get the used code.

Here's some pseudocode to demonstrate how you extract the used code:

```
const file = json[0];
const text = file.text;
let usedCode = '';
for (let i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
  const range = ranges[i];
  usedCode += text.substring(range.start, range.end);
}
```

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/devtools#coverage